# PyAutoGUI with Selenium remote?

Tags: python, selenium, pyautogui, selenoid, selenium-remotedriver

I am using Selenoid (or just selenium remote) with python and want to use pyautogui with it.

Is there any ways to do that?

I will be thankfull for any information!

Answer (score 0):

You can look Action Chains. It is part of selenium.

Comment: I am trying to click elements that are not on browser page